# Problem with complex number

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers

I can not understand how answer is $-4+i \sqrt 3$ is there any one help me to understand this? Thanks.

$$u=(-3)+2\omega= -4+i \sqrt 3.$$

Comment: How do you define $w$?

Comment: What was the difficulty you faced? Are you familiar with addition and multiplication of complex numbers in general?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems, $w=-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sqrt3}{2}i,$ which gives:
$$-3+2w=-4+\sqrt3i.$$
See also the context. Maybe was written something like $w^3=1$?